# Polymer REST backend

Tags: rest, polymer

I have a backend written in golang exposing /api/list interface. It returns lists when called from GET and create new list when it receive POST with parameters.
I can read it with standard core-ajax element, there is a huge amount of examples to do that.

What I didn't understood is what should I do, when I want to create new element through POST? I read the documentation and searched for sample code for half day, can you point me to right direction?
//
Ok, thanks for help, it was really only bad format of json I was sending. There is still dark cloud in my mind telling that I misunderstood something from conceptual view. Is this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="channels-service" attributes="channels">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
    <core-ajax id="ch_load"
      auto
      url="/api/list"
      on-core-response="{{channelsLoaded}}"
      handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
    <core-ajax id="ch_update"
      url="/api/list"
      on-core-response="{{channelsUpdated}}"
      method="POST"
      handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('channels-service', {
    created: function() {
      this.channels = [];
    },
    channelsLoaded: function() {
      // Make a copy of the loaded data
      this.channels = this.$.ch_load.response.slice(0);
    },
    newChannel: function(ch_name) {
     // this.$.ch_update.body = "ch_name";
     this.$.ch_update.body = '{"Name":"pitchalist2"}'
      this.$.ch_update.go();
    },
    channelsUpdated: function() {
      //window.log(this.$.ch_update.response.slice(0));
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

correctly written data layer? It looks very counterintuitive to me and in examples using local data storage it works way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a POST request by setting the method attribute (`method="POST"`) and the body attribute (`body='{"my":"data"}'`). Indeed you need a second *iron-ajax* element for this request.

See the attributes section in the [iron-ajax documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax).

Comment: I'm wondering if there's something which will wrap the core-ajax into a core-rest so you don't have to create one element for each endpoint * each method.